# Vuejs Component doesn't show up when route changes with router-link

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vue-router

I am creating a theme with WP Rest API with Vuejs. I have created dynamic routes to blog titles and linked with router-link. When I click on a title, the url changes but the component is not showing up. I just get a blank page. Here is my code:

index.php

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>    

<template id="post-list-template">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="post-list">
            <article v-for="post in posts">
                <router-link :to="{name:'post', params:{slug: post.slug}}"><h2>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2></router-link>
                <p v-html="post.excerpt.rendered"></p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<template id="single-post-template">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
</template>
```

app.js

```
 var singlePost= Vue.extend({
    template: '#single-post-template'

});


var router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {path: '/', component: postList},
        {path:'post/:slug', name:'post', component: singlePost}
    ]
});



new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    router: router,
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error, try `Vue.component` instead of `Vue.extend` for `singlePost `.

Comment: No errors. "Hello World" appears for a second when clicked on the link.

Comment: Okay, I found the mistake. There should be a slash at the start of the second path - '/post/:slug'